# Feature an article on news page in Joomla

Tags: joomla

This might be a really simple question and I apologise if it has been asked before.

I I'm creating a website for a school with Joomla 2.5 and I want the homepage to be a blog list of the latest news. Just above the news blog I am trying to insert a featured article to introduce the school

My problem is that I can insert the featured article by setting the homepage as featured article list and I can make the news feed by setting the homepage as a blog list. I however do not know how to set both at once

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the homepage as a blog list (configure your menu item as you probably already did according to your question) and insert the featured article creating an `Articles Category` module, in the settings of the module:

- Go to filtering options (right side) and choose in Featured articles `Only`.
- Still there, type `1` in the Count box.
- Select the category that the article belongs to.
- Assign the module to be shown only in the homepage.
- Assign a position to the module above the main content (the blog list).

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are trying to display a specific piece of content belonging to that category on top of the rest of the articles ...

You should do this simply by inserting this article as a description for this category.

Open the category, on the description insert the content as if it's an article then on the menu link make sure you are showing the category description ... this way the article will always be on top doesn't matter if any article is inserted. If that's not what you meant to do please update your question.